# Как можно заменить последний элемент в строке?

Tags: python

Необходимо прочитать строку и заменить последний элемент типа !? на точку. подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это можно сделать

Comment: воспоьзуйтесь regex `[!\?]$` на `.'

Comment: а это встроенная функция в питоне? а нельзя ли обойтись без нее, я пробовала делать через срезы, но потом вспомнила, что строка неизменяемый объект

Comment: если просто последний символ string[:-1]+'.'

Comment: можете взять и сравнить string[-1] == '?' or string[-1] == '!'

Comment: '''
def format(text):
    if text[-1] == '!' or text[-1] == '?':
        text1 = text[:1] + '.'
        return text1.strip().title()

print(format('    I wanna go home!      '))
'''

Comment: не получается, выводит none

Comment: да, только я бы стрип сделал в начале функции

Comment: теперь выводит только точку :)

Comment: вы по мелочевке понаошибались в индексах. Все поправили? `def format(text):
  text1 = text.strip()
  if text1[-1] == '!' or text1[-1] == '?':
  text1 = text1[:-1] + '.' 
  return text1.title() 
print(format(' I wanna go home! '))`

Comment: и text1 надо инициализировать в любом случае

Comment: что значит инициализировать? и вот если я в конце напишу несколько !!! или !??? символов, как можно все заменить на точки, воспользоваться for?

Comment: while пока условие выполняется. инициализировать - дать ему значение. У вас, если if не выполняется text1 не определено

Comment: И еще - вы могли в функции использовать переменную text, не боясь ее испортить в вызывающем коде, если вы из-за этого завели text1

Comment: да мне просто пока удобнее писать новые переменные, чтобы понимать последовательность действий, а вот с while что-то не получается

Comment: добавлять пока нечего, потому что я просто вместо if написала while, наверное, так не стоило делать

Comment: `text[:-1] + '.' if text[-1] in '!?' else text[-1]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно:

```
res=text[:-1] + (lambda x: x if x not in ['!','?'] else '.')(text[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 'qweqwe?!'
s = a[:-1] + '.' if a[-1] in '?!' else a
```